# Как прижать навигационную панель к правому краю родительского блока?

Tags: html, css

столкнулся с проблемой, что блок навигации *.nav-bar* не прижимается к правому краю родительского блока *.header*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
}

.nav-bar {
  width: 540px;
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
}

.nav-bar__list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-bar__item a {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/223/300/200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <ul class="nav-bar__list">
      <li class="nav-bar__item"><a href="" class="test">Главная</a></li>
      <li class="nav-bar__item"><a href="">Продукты</a></li>
      <li class="nav-bar__item"><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
      <li class="nav-bar__item"><a href="">О нас</a></li>
      <li class="nav-bar__item"><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: justify space-between нужно для header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`justify-content: space-between` в шапку, вот изменил чуток размеры для наглядности

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
}

.nav-bar {
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
}

.nav-bar__list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-bar__item a {
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/223/100/100" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <ul class="nav-bar__list">
      <li class="nav-bar__item"><a href="" class="test">Главная</a></li>
      <li class="nav-bar__item"><a href="">Продукты</a></li>
      <li class="nav-bar__item"><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
      <li class="nav-bar__item"><a href="">О нас</a></li>
      <li class="nav-bar__item"><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```